# BFT vs On-chain POW

Tags: security, casper

What significant advantages does **BFT** provide over **On-chain POW** solutions and why or why not are they not more commonly used?

Comment: Hi there. Is this a general blockchain question, or does it have some specific relation to Ethereum?

Comment: @RichardHorrocks It was mentioned on the documentation of Casper FFG

Comment: @VigneshKarthikeyan If my answer is sufficient then please accept it and close the question, otherwise, are there other points of clarification that I can help with?

Comment: I'm looking for more depth in the answer. What causes these differences?

Answer (score 1):

Answers can be found in [Ethereum's official Q&A on Proof of Stake](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Proof-of-Stake-FAQ) under the `How does proof of stake fit into traditional Byzantine fault tolerance research?` section.

> Proof of work algorithms and chain-based proof of stake algorithms choose availability over consistency, but BFT-style consensus algorithms lean more toward consistency; Tendermint chooses consistency explicitly, and Casper uses a hybrid model that prefers availability but provides as much consistency as possible and makes both on-chain applications and clients aware of how strong the consistency guarantee is at any given time.